# Como deixar um elemento invisível quando o valor é 0?

Tags: css

Estou fazendo uma espécie de "sistema de notificações" bem simples em `CSS`.

O que eu quero, é que quando o número de notificações for `(0)` ele fique com `display:none;`.

Conheço um jeito que eu acho que é possível fazer.

Ex: `.bolinha [style*="text-align:center;"] { display:none; }` <- Acho que é possível adapta-lo, só não sei como fazer.

Vou deixar uma imagem ilustrando para um melhor entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faça o mesmo sistema que muda o número do elemento mudar o estilo.

Segue exemplo em PHP, adapte para a linguagem do seu sistema:

```php
// Antes:
echo "<span class=\"bolinha\">$comentarios</span>";

// Mude para:
$estilo=($comentarios==0)?'invisivel':'bolinha';
echo "<span class=\"$estilo\">$comentarios</span>";
```

Aí basta criar o `.invisivel {display: none}`.

Ou com JS:

```
contador = document.getElementById("contador");
contador.className = (contador.innerHTML == '0')?'invisivel':'bolinha';
```

Não esqueça de por o `id="contador"` no elemento, ou atualizar o JS pro id já existente.

> Veja o demo no **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/UUJPQ/)** (mude o valor e aperte Run).

Comment: Para ser mais claro, quero integrá-lo ao WHMCS.
E ele não é de código aberto, ou seja, é tudo criptografado.
Queria algo somente com CSS. :(

Comment: Nem JS dá pra por?

Comment: Sim!!!!!!!!!!! :D :D :D :D

Comment: Eu já iria perguntar se era possível com JS. :D

Comment: Muito booooooom......
Obrigadão @Bacco você é demais!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes só não esqueça que se for um JS que atualiza o contador, você deve incluir estas duas linhas dentro do atualizador, ou chamar com algum timer. Aí só vendo o caso concreto mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente usando apenas `CSS` não é possível selecionar um elemento pelo seu texto. Uma opção seria colocar um atributo neste elemento para diferenciá-lo, exemplo:

Em seu elemento `span`, coloque um atributo, por exemplo `data-value`:

```
<span class="bolinha" data-value="0">0</span>
```

E no CSS, faça:

```
span.bolinha[data-value="0"]{display:none;} /*Oculta o elemento com data-value="0"*/
```

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vdwz2/)**

Comment: Excelente dica!

Comment: Vou usar a dica do @Bacco para esse projeto, e vou usar sua brilhante dica para outro projeto! Vai ficar muito legal! Obrigadooooo......

Comment: @AlexandreLopes fico feliz em ajudar.